# Controller method issue in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

This is my Controller method wherein I want to fetch posts by user id.
I also have relationship defined in User model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post','user_id','id');
}
```

UserController.php

```
use App\Post;
public function findPostsByUser($id){
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);    
    $posts = $user->posts()->get();
    return $posts;
}
```

But it is giving me 'Post' not found error. Can someone help on this.

Comment: Please update this first `>hasMany('Post','user_id','id')` to `>hasMany('App\Post','user_id','id')`

Comment: If you wont to get only posts use `Post::where('user_id', $id)->get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **Post** model make sure you have the relation defined like this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And change your **User** model to this:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id','id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change relation method to

```
use App\Post;
....
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class,'user_id','id');
}
```

or

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id','id');
}
```

If you wont to get only posts that case use this

```
public function findPostsByUser($id){
    $posts = Post::where('user_id', $id)->get();
    return $posts;
}
```

The second solution has 1 query, but first solution has 2 query in db.

Also you can do it this way

```
public function findPostsByUser($id){
    $posts = Post::whereUserId($id)->get();
    return $posts;
}
```